# How does 'category__not_in' differ to cat => '-1'?

Tags: wp-query

As the title reads, I'd like to exclude certain categories. It appears I can either use `'category__not_in'` or `cat` to prune the list. I'm unsure if one is better than the other and if so how. WP VIP for example recommends staying away from `[post__not_in][1]` so does `'category__not_in'` fall in the same camp?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the codebase, the only difference appears to be that `category__not_in` [excludes child terms](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1257) from selection, whereas `cat` [does not](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1216).

Should `category__not_in` be used with caution, similar to `posts__not_in`? Absolutely, but for different reasons. The main issue with excluding posts is that it causes problems for caching - every query with a different excluded post ID requires a separate cache entry, significantly negating the advantage of caching. Excluding terms, meanwhile, [requires more JOINs](https://docs.wpvip.com/technical-references/code-review/vip-warnings/) in the query, and is therefore detrimental to performance.